# Can update to a ParentTable cause lookup in Child table with foreign Key relationship in SQL SERVER 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, transactions

following tables are part of Database Design. 
I donot have any Non-Clustered index on my Foreign Keys.

[image]

I am locking PatientChartImages table by using the following command

```
begin transaction t1
update PatientChartImages set RotationAngle = 55
--ROLLBACK TRANSACTION t1
```

After that, All updates to the User Table are timing out.I am attaching the SqlProfiler trace. The selected command in that image is causing TimeOut. since I am updating PatientChartImages and CreatedByUserId in PatientChartImages is not a FK to main user table, why are Fk lookups causing TimeOut.

According to Me, the following sequence is happening

1. Transaction has a Exclusive lock on PatientChartImages
2. Since PatientChartid in PatientChartImages  is a FK to PatientChartid in PatientCharts, this is causing Foreign Key Lookup and is locking PatientCharts table.
3. Similarly as CreatedByUserId in PatientCharts table   is a FK to UserID in Users table,so FK lookups are also locking Users table.

Is my understanding on this correct? Please suggest and also tell me how can i prevent this kind of locking.

**Trace ScreenShot**
[image]

Comment: why is the rollback commented out? why is it there in the first place?

Comment: IsPatientAlreadyExists ?  That seems like a very odd property?

Comment: Modifying UserID in User table or deleting a row in User table will need to check the two FK's in PatientCharts. IT's hard to see if that is what you are doing in the picture.

Comment: I am replication a issue. I am creating a scenerio in which a long running transaction is currently going on. Thats why rollback transaction is commented out.

Comment: The exact query is exec sp_executesql N'update [dbo].[Users]
set [LoginId] = @0
where ([UserId] = @1)
',N'@0 varchar(200),@1 uniqueidentifier',@0='arun.sharma',@1='0A5EBB78-9293-E011-8BCB-7071BCBD6F81'

Comment: With the transaction left open, and running the second query that hangs, from another connection run sp_lock (or use sys.dm_tran_locks). Look for the rows with a status of "WAIT" - that's the resource blocking your second query from completing.

Comment: *I do not have any Non-Clustered index on my Foreign Keys* - but you really should have! Helps both performance, and also reduces locking

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure your understanding of the situation is correct.

As you obviously know, when performing a SQL transaction, any update which can affect the tables you're updating needs to be prevented. Think about the ACID principles (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ACID).

I think the only way round this is to use `READ UNCOMMITTED` or `NOLOCK`

> Implements dirty read, or isolation
>   level 0 locking, which means that no
>   shared locks are issued and no
>   exclusive locks are honored. When this
>   option is set, it is possible to read
>   uncommitted or dirty data; values in
>   the data can be changed and rows can
>   appear or disappear in the data set
>   before the end of the transaction.
>   This option has the same effect as
>   setting `NOLOCK` on all tables in all
>   `SELECT` statements in a transaction.
>   This is the least restrictive of the
>   four isolation levels.

You can work out the risks of this for yourself.

I actually think the answer is to keep the transaction as short as possible and put up with it, as it's only doing this to protect data integrity. e.g. only start and end the transaction around the actual update operations.

I hope this helps a bit.

Comment: using READ UNCOMMITTED does not help. still the table is locked.

Comment: It will let you read from the tables, but it won't let you alter them as they will still be locked by the transaction.